# Dynamic Programming with "broken profile"?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The following link mentions some types of dynamic programming:
http://www.mii.lt/olympiads_in_informatics/pdf/INFOL056.pdf
one of which is "broken profile".

I am pretty sure it is a valid term since I have seen references to it in other programming competition sites like TopCoder and CodeForces.

But I can't seem to find anything on this topic. This term has been used mostly by Russian sources.

Does anyone what if means, or what kind of problems within dynamic programming it solves? Or even better a tutorial?

Comment: http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=697369&start=0

Comment: @nhahtdh Yea, that's where I started before I posted this question. To be honest, I found the going tough with that recipe, which is why I was looking for a more gentle introduction in the first place. What I would love to know is the source used by that author when learning this stuff. I don't know of any book that covers those topics.

Comment: I think the link should at least tell you what kind of problem it solves. I'm also interested in what this broken-profile is about. There is a link on codeforce that talks about another example of broken-profile: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/5806

Comment: Requesting administrators to move this question to some other forum (maybe programmers stack exchange? where this would be more relevant and is likely to see more responses) if this question is off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: ^ also the topcoder link is locked now... @nhahtdh